how to setup Grpc status and code in golang with Client
camera, err := db.ClientDB.GetCamera(ctx, in.CameraId)     if err != nil {      fmt.Println("err", err)         if errors.Is(err, errors.New("camera not found")) {             return nil, status.Error(codes.NotFound, "Camera not found")         }         return nil, status.Error(codes.Internal, "Problem getting camera apps")     }

message GetCameraApplicationsResponse {   vision.core.CameraAppCollection camera_apps = 1; }

export async function getCameraApplications(   cameraId: string ): Promise<GetCameraApplicationsResponse> {   try {     var request: GetCameraApplicationsRequest =       new GetCameraApplicationsRequest();     request.cameraId = cameraId;     console.log("request.cameraId", cameraId)     const response = await client.getCameraApplications(request);     console.log({response})     return response;   } catch (error: any) {     console.log({error})     if (error instanceof ConnectError) {       switch (error.code) {         case Code.NotFound:           throw new Error('Camera not found');         case Code.InvalidArgument:           throw new Error('Invalid camera ID');         default:           throw new Error('Error fetching camera applications: ' + error.message);       }     }     throw error;   } }

I am trying to setup Grpc status and code, For invalid cameraId i am getting
{
    "error": {
        "name": "ConnectError",
        "rawMessage": "missing trailer",
        "code": 2,
        "metadata": {},
        "details": [],
        "cause": "missing trailer"
    }
}

For success Its working perfectly.

Please add all the Code proper formatted currently its...

In addition to the above please provide more info on how this is deployed (is the javascript running under node or in a browser, if it's browser based then add info on your use of grpc-web).
